# How to generate a 3d triangle surface (trisurf) plot in python with matplotlib (the data is prepared)?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, 3d

I have three lists of data: X,Y,Z and trying to generate a 3d trisurf plot (i did both in MATLAB and in Python) with them.

The problem is the plot seems to lose something, in MATLAB it's `K = boundary(X,Y,Z,1); trisurf(K, X, Y, Z, 'FaceAlpha', 0.1)`.

**trisurf in Python (matplotlib):**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
%matplotlib inline

# data (X,Y,Z) for three-dimensional scattered points: **in the end of this post**

# plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z,
                cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none');

ax.set_xlabel('kp')
ax.set_ylabel('ki')
ax.set_zlabel('pcg of min time delay (%)')
ax.set_title("f-t curve(s)")
```

Before using MATLAB, we need to use Python to put the data into a csv file:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'kp':X, 'ki':Y, 'pcgTd (%)':Z})
df.to_csv('cur.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

**In MATLAB, we can use:**

```
% if you store data in a csv file
num = xlsread('YOUR_ADDRESS/cur.csv', 'A2:C518');
X = num(:,1);
Y = num(:,2);
Z = num(:,3);
K = boundary(X, Y, Z, 1);
trisurf(K, X, Y, Z, 'FaceAlpha', 0.1)

colorbar
xlabel('kp')
ylabel('ki')
zlabel('delay (sec)')
xlim([0.05 3.2]);
ylim([0.01 0.06]);
zlim([100 200]);
set(gca,'XTick',[0.05:0.05:3.2])
set(gca,'YTick',[0.01:0.01:0.06])
set(gca,'ZTick',[100:50:200])
```

How can I fix the 3d plot problem in **Python** (boundary or ...)?

matplotlib version:
[image: python matplotlib 3d]
MATLAB version (goal):
[image: matlab 3d]

**p.s.,** basically, the 3d plot is based on three 2d layers (Z=100,150,200), and you can see, from MATLAB diagram and from the three 2d diagrams, the dots are shrunk if Z is higher.
[image: Z=100]
[image: Z=150]
[image: Z=200]

```
Data: X = [0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.15, 2.15, 2.15, 2.15, 2.15, 2.15, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.45, 2.45, 2.5, 2.55]

Y = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]

Z = [100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 100.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that this question was asked a while ago, but I figured I'd take a quick shot at answering. You can calculate the data's convex hull with `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` and use the `simplices` for plotting the triangles. Here's an example using your data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

X = np.asarray([0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.05, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.15, 2.15, 2.15, 2.15, 2.15, 2.15, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.45, 2.45, 2.5, 2.55])
Y = np.asarray([0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01])
Z = np.asarray([100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 100.0, 150.0, 100.0, 100.0])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

points = np.column_stack((X, Y, Z))
hull = ConvexHull(points)

ax.plot(X, Y, Z, 'bo', ms=2)
ax.plot(points[hull.vertices, 0],
        points[hull.vertices, 1],
        points[hull.vertices, 2], 'ko', markersize=4)
s = ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, triangles=hull.simplices,
                    cmap='viridis', alpha=0.2, edgecolor='k')
plt.colorbar(s, shrink=0.7)

plt.show()
```

Note that this is a different method from your Matlab example. Also, I only plotted the interior points in blue to illustrate your data. The points that appear in the convex hull are returned as `vertices` and are plotted as larger, black markers.

[convex hull for trisurf3d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7jhh.png)